# Pop off array within Javascript for loop not getting all array items

Tags: javascript, for-loop, stack

I'm trying to figure out why the following piece of code only pops the last 3 items off the array but not the last two.

```
var test = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'];

console.log('length - '+test.length);

for(var k = 0; k <= test.length; k++) {
    var tests = test.pop();
    console.log(tests+' - '+k);
}
```

The results for the above code:

```
length - 5
(index):30 test5 - 0
(index):30 test4 - 1
(index):30 test3 - 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method modifies the original array, so of course for-loop will only visit half of the values until array is fully emptied.

What you can do is to use while loop instead:

```js
var test = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'];

console.log('length - ' + test.length);

while (test.length) {
  var tests = test.pop();
  console.log(tests);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the length of the array is changing while the loop is executing, so the test 
 `k <= test.length` is changing with each execution.

```js
var test = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'];

console.log('length - '+test.length);

for ( var k = 0, len = test.length; k < len; k++ ) {
  var tests = test.pop();
  console.log(tests+' - '+k);
}
```

Or with a `while` loop:

```js
var test = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'];

console.log('length - '+test.length);

var k = 0;
while (test.length) {
    var tests = test.pop();
    console.log(tests+' - '+(k++));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're increasing `k` each time. After printing `2`, `k == 3` while there are still 2 elements left in the list. But since `k > test.length`, the loop ends.

If you really still want to keep count, increase `k` but don't test it:

```js
var test = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'];

console.log('length - ' + test.length);

for (var k = 0; test.length > 0; k++) {
  var tests = test.pop();
  console.log(tests + ' - ' + k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the logic of what you're doing... you're burning your candle at both ends (so to speak).

k = 0, length = 5 ('test1')
at this point test5 is thrown away (that's what pop does, [it drops the last element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop))

k = 1, length = 4 ('test2') (at this point test4 is thrown away)

and so on... after 3 iterations your array is 3 items.

I *think what you're trying to do you would accomplish with [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
while(myArray.length > 0){
   console.log(myArray[0])
   myArray.splice(0,1)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep your code style, just added following line. This is to prevent array length re-sizing in the for loop:

```
var arrSize = test.length;
```

Your final code would look like this:

```
<script>
    var test = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'];

    var arrSize = test.length;

    console.log('length - ' + arrSize);

    for (var k = 0; k < arrSize; k++) {
        var tests = test.pop();
        console.log(tests + ' - ' + k);
    }
</script>
```